# Type variable in protocol - Swift 2

Tags: xcode, protocols, swift2

So I have a protocol, and in it I want a variable that is a class type. That way I can init that class from the variable.

Keep in mind that there will be many different classes. I made a quick example.

I get the error "type 'CashRegister' does not conform to protocol 'RegisterProtocol'"

This example isn't exactly what I'm doing, but it gets the point across. Thanks for the help.

```
protocol RegisterProtocol {
    var currentBill: DollarBillProtocol {get set}
    func makeNewBill()->DollarBillProtocol
}

extension RegisterProtocol {
    func printCurrentBill() {
        Swift.print(currentBill)
    }
}

class CashRegister: RegisterProtocol {

    var currentBill = OneDollarBill.self

    func makeNewBill() -> DollarBillProtocol {
        return currentBill.init()
    }
}



protocol DollarBillProtocol {
    // protocol that all bills have in common
}


class OneDollarBill: DollarBillProtocol {
    required init(){
    }
}

class FiveDollarBill: DollarBillProtocol {
    required init(){
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you declare `currentBill` in `CashRegister` makes it a var of type `class`. But the protocol `RegisterProtocol` requires this variable to be of type `DollarBillProtocol` in any class that implements the protocol. The compile error is because of this mismatch.

To make this more clear, you could declare the var with the explicit type, as follows:

```
class CashRegister: RegisterProtocol {

    var currentBill: DollarBillProtocol = OneDollarBill() // or other initial value
}
```

Comment: I have it in the CashRegister class... I don't want a strong reference to an object. I want a reference to the type.

Comment: Sorry. but that isn't answering the question. I know that would work, but it's not what I want. I don't want to init a object for the variable. I just want to store the type. Then later init it. Look at the makeNewBill call.

Comment: I want a class type var. How to I make that work with the protocol?

Comment: in that case you to have ensure that OneDollarBill.Type conform to DollarBillProtocol. but do you think, that it is possible? not at all ...