# Swift doesn't recognize Type variables

Tags: ios, swift, variables, types, protocols

In my project I am having an issue with Swift, that it doesn't recognize variables containing protocol types. This means I can't use a variable that stores a type, to check if the type of an instance matches it.

I attached problematic part of the code with some brief context.

Is this some kind of bug or am I overseeing something really badly?

Using XCode 7.3, Swift 2.2

```
//Context of Issue BEGIN

class TaskValueObject {
    //ManyData, VeryComplexity, SoBig, wow..
}

typealias TaskListSorterBlock = (TaskValueObject, TaskValueObject) -> Bool

protocol TaskListSorter : class {
    init()
    var localizedTitle : String { get }
    var sorterBlock : TaskListSorterBlock { get }
}

class PriorityTaskListSorter : TaskListSorter {
    // ... Implementation ...
}
// Many other TaskListSorter implementation classes ...

//Context of Issue END

class TaskListContainer {

    weak var currentSorter : TaskListSorter?
    var sorters : [TaskListSorter]
    init() {
        self.sorters = [ PriorityTaskListSorter(), /* ... Instances created for <TaskListSorter> implementing class ... */ ]
        loadDefaultSorter()
    }

    static var defaultSorterType : TaskListSorter.Type = PriorityTaskListSorter.self

    private func loadDefaultSorter() {
        let defaultSorterType = TaskListContainer.defaultSorterType
        for sorter in self.sorters {
            if sorter is defaultSorterType {
                //       ^ ERROR HERE : defaultSorterType is not a 'type'
                self.currentSorter = sorter
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Update 1: I get the same error if I replace the problematic line with the following:

```
if let defaultSorter = sorter as? defaultSorterType {
```

Update 2: Replacing the problematic line with the one below, makes the code work. However I am using here the 'dynamicType' which is not offered by code completion (must be a reason for that...). Also the question remains, why the first 2 attempts didn't work?

```
if sorter.dynamicType == defaultSorterType {
```

Comment: Why not just use `if sorter is PriorityTaskListSorter`?

Comment: We are developing a highly modular and configureable application. This part of the code is contained in the Core target project and the type defaultSorter has to be configurable from a distribution app (from an external build target). So we can't hardcode this.

Comment: that may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32858573/type-variable-in-protocol-swift-2